# Visting Colomares Castle from outside

Tags: europe, spain, architecture, malaga, andalusia

I am planning to visit the Colomares Castle on a Tuesday. According to the website, these are the summer timings for Tuesdays:

From 10:00 a.m. at 2:00 p.m.
From 5:00 p.m. at 9:00 p.m.

I am afraid I won't be there in an optimal time-frame. What if I reach by 3pm? Can I still have a good look from outside? Or would be not be useful at all.

Is it even worth going inside? Can we really go inside the castle or is the entry just for a park or something?

Answer (score 4):

[Google Street View](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@36.5905448,-4.5729885,3a,75y,72.66h,92.28t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1saWz9AH2oWt7qsWPyX9u9nQ!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?entry=ttu) shows a high wall and an entrance gate.

If the castle is closed, it's reasonable to suppose that the gate is closed. You could peer through the bars, but descriptions on [Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g562812-d669392-Reviews-Castillo_Monumento_Colomares-Benalmadena_Costa_del_Sol_Province_of_Malaga_Andaluci.html) suggest you really need to go onto the site.

The site is a [monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castillo_de_Colomares) to Christopher Columbus built in the form of a castle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll be limited to seeing the structure from the outside.

The [Colomares website](https://www.castillomonumentocolomares.com) contains (towards the bottom) this text:

> TARIFAS
> PARA VISITAS TURÍSTICAS
>
> ADULTOS: 3.00 €
>
> NIÑOS Y PENSIONISTAS: 2.00 €
>
> NOTA: El monumento se visita de manera exterior únicamente

The last line can be translated into English as *The monument may only be seen from the outside.*

In addition, the same website contains [two pages of photos of the monument](https://www.castillomonumentocolomares.com/fotos/). All the photos are exterior views, none show any interior or rooms. There may not be any interior rooms, I don't know, I've never been there.

Comment: Some of the photos on Wikicommons appear to be shot from within the walls but perhaps the guided tour takes you inside.